# Does LDAP provide a token after binding, so I don't have to send credentials every time?

Tags: ldap

I have a web application (PHP, but doesn't matter).  It uses LDAP for authentication (already working), and it allows users to search LDAP (already working).

But when searching, I use a generic process account to bind() and then run the search().

What I would like is to use the LDAP account that logs in to be the same account that binds for the searching.  But the only way I see to do that is to store the user's credentials in the sessions (bad!).

Nutshell: can I get a "state/session/??" token from LDAP, to bind() and then search() on subsequent http requests?

(btw, using Active Directory.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basic LDAP doesn't provide anything like this.  The credentials that you present when binding are used for the rest of the connection, so if you could keep an LDAP connection open across multiple HTTP requests (and share LDAP connections among however many server jobs you have running), then you could avoid saving credentials.

There are various extensions to LDAP floating around (including several within Active Directory), so it's possible that one of those adds sessions-across-connections, but if so, I'm not aware of it.

As a sort-of-workaround, because Active Directory supports GSSAPI and because of how Kerberos works, you ought to be able to use the user's credentials to request a Kerberos ticket for accessing LDAP then store that ticket as your "state/session/??" token.  This Kerberos ticket would only be valid for accessing LDAP and would auto-expire, so this would avoid the pitfalls of storing the user's credentials in the session.  I don't know if your LDAP library supports GSSAPI and would give you enough control to do this or not.

Comment: The authenticated identity is not used for the "rest of the connection", the authenticated identity is used on the connection until the next BIND on the connection, assuming that LDAPv3 is in use.